# react native how can I pass a ref

Tags: react-native

I have a component with function:

```
 const selectImage = () => {
        const options = {
          maxWidth: 2000,
          maxHeight: 2000,
          storageOptions: {
            skipBackup: true,
            path: 'images'
          }
        };
       launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
          if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled image picker');
          } else if (response.error) {
            console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
          } else if (response.customButton) {
            console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
          } else {
            const source = { uri: response.uri };
            console.log(source);
            setImage(source);
          }
        });
      };



      const uploadImage = async () => {
        const { uri } = image;
        console.log('uri check:', uri) //stands for the image location
        const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        setUploading(true);
        setTransferred(0);
        const task = storage()
          .ref(filename)
          .putFile(uri);
        // set progress state
        task.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
          setTransferred(
            Math.round(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 10000
          );
        });
        try {
          await task;
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
        setUploading(false);
        Alert.alert(
          'Photo uploaded!',
          'Your photo has been uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage!'
        );
        setImage(null);
      };
```

that was to pick an image and upload to firebase, so i get the imageUri.

I want to add that image-uri into firestore, just need to get the correct ref  instead of put all the code in one place.

on the other screen I just call `<UploadImage/>`.

can anyone guide me or give some information?

Comment: Insert full code please

Comment: I think to use React.forwardRef but I cant understand it well. sorry for my weak english